# Enterprise iOS app release, need a https server, how to set it up with express.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https

Long story short, I build an app for my company, bundle up, then it is required a https server for app to release. I want to do it with express.js. How? BTW, I don't want to bother CA for certificate and key, can I use openssl to self generate all of that, and make it running?

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./keys/myserver.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./keys/myserver.crt'),
  passphrase: '1234'
};
```

How do I get myserver.key and myserver.crt?

Answer (score 0):

Super delayed answer but you can generate them with your terminal.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```